# Remove parent xml tag based on child value

Tags: php, xml, parsing

For example, we have xml file with this format:

```
<A>
      <B>
            <C></C>
            <D></D>
            <D></D>
      </B>
</A>
```

i need that:
if all "D"-tags elements are empty, then we need to delete whole "A"-tag element

and, of course, we need to do this with all "A"-tags in xml.

Comment: What xml parser are you using? What output do youu want? We need more to answer thhis question.

Comment: output - same xml-format string, without "A"-tags included empty "D"-tags.
For parsing i usually use DomDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this algorithm:

- find all the B elements
- for each B element, find all the D elements
- for each D element, check if it's empty
- if all D elements are empty, fetch the parent of B and remove it from the tree

To do it with the DOM extension, see:

- [DOMDocument::loadXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php)
- [DOMNode::childNodes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.childnodes) or (less strict) [DOMElement::getElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php)
- [DOMNode::removeChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php)

Comment: thanks for great answer!
but the best answer would be just an example of code ;)

Comment: @cru3l: fyi, code snippets provided in answers are more likely when code snippets are provided in questions.